# Remove a precise curve from a figure in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

If I do the following

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
list1=[1,2,3]
list2=[4,5,6]
fig1=plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(list1)
plt.plot(list2)
plt.show()
```

I will plot in the same figure both list1 and list2. What should I do if later I decide that I need only to plot list1 in the figure and I want to remove the curve of list2 ?
If possible, I would like to do it without using add_subplot or other similar commands. I am assuming that the xlim and ylim are the same for the two curves.

Comment: Can't you just re-render the plot without `plt.plot(list2)`?

Comment: Yes but I would like to do it for more complicated figures. If possible, I would like to avoid to re-render all the curves that I need any time I want to remove one of them.

Comment: Are you running this in some interactive mode in Ipython or jupyter? In which case you still have the figure open and want to remove the line?

Comment: I should have explained it better. I want to save several curves in a for loop. So I might need, inside the for loop, to for example save two curves, then remove one, then add another one and save again.

Comment: Always ask about what you really want to do to avoid [xyproblems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is three possibilities:

**Way 1** - *hide the curve (but keep the data)*:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
list1=[1,2,3]
list2=[4,5,6]
fig1=plt.figure(1)
plot_list1 = plt.plot(list1)
plot_list2 = plt.plot(list2)
plt.setp(plot_list2,"visible",False) #hide the list2 curve
plt.show()
```

**Way 2** - *Remove the data*:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
list1=[1,2,3]
list2=[4,5,6]
fig1=plt.figure(1)
plot_list1 = plt.plot(list1)
plot_list2 = plt.plot(list2)
plt.setp(plot_list2,"data",([],[])) #remove list2 data
plt.show()
```

**Way 3** - *Remove the curve*:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
list1=[1,2,3]
list2=[4,5,6]
fig1=plt.figure(1)
plot_list1 = plt.plot(list1)
plot_list2 = plt.plot(list2)
plot_list2[0].remove()
plt.show()
```

Comment: I added a third (and easiest) way.

Comment: Here it is! The third method is precisely what I was looking for ;)